# root cannot list files in /data

Tags: adb, superuser

```
1|shell@maguro:/ # ls -l /system/xbin/
-rwxr-xr-x root     shell       59816 2013-07-11 02:12 dexdump
-rwsr-sr-x root     root        67008 2013-10-08 17:24 su
shell@maguro:/ # ls /data
opendir failed, Permission denied
```

The permissions on `su` are correct right? I get the hash prompt, but I can't list the files in /data (or do anything that requires superuser permissions). I don't have Superuser.apk installed, I don't want to install it because of that grant/deny access dialogue that pops up if you wipe the device. What does Superuser.apk do that I can't do when I unpack the *.img files?

Comment: Perhaps you should install a file manager. I recommend CyanogenMod's. Also, SuperUser is the bridge between the su file and the application. AFAIK, you cannot create that connection yourself.

Comment: if SuperUser can, so can I. I just need to know how. File manager won't help me, I need adb shell root access for more than browsing files.

Comment: Perhaps we can help if you tell us what you want to do instead of giving us pieces at a time :)

Comment: I need full root permissions to adb shell to run the android shell commands, add/remove/read files, and turn services on/off pragmatically for testing purposes. And although I know how to automate the UI, I need to do all of this without the UI in order to reduce the time that is required to initialize the device for testing. And I need to maintain ADB and root access after a factory reset.

Comment: You would need to root your device to do what you want, which requires root access. I'm going to add this info to my answer.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Since 4.3 just having `/system/xbin/su` with suid root permissions is not enough, because there is additional protection using the capability bounding set (and maybe SELinux), which prevents the traditional way of `su` operation (you get the uid 0, but no privileges). You need to have a recent enough `su` and start `su --daemon &` during boot to get full root permissions (the latter is usually done by placing the command to start the daemon into `/system/etc/install-recovery.sh`).

Comment: @SergeyVlasov how can I verify I have the appropriate `su` binary?

Answer (score -1):

Enter `su` first.

> > su
>   > ls /data

Make sure your device is rooted.

Comment: I do, and I get the hash prompt (#) but that's about the only thing that changes, I have regular user privileges, not super user privileges.

Answer (score -1):

For some operations, adb must be running as root as well.
You can easily restart the adb daemon with root permission by running `adb root`.
Then you can enter `adb shell` again, switch to root with `su` and navigate wherever you'd like.

Worked for me when I had exactly the same problem.
(Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Custom AOSP-based KitKat 4.4.4)

Small addition for others:
Certain superuser apps have an option in configuration to allow root access to either apps, adb or both. The default is not necessarily to allow adb root access.

Comment: The first point is true for ADB operations (such as `adb push` or `adb pull`), but not for shell operations AFAIK. Might be device/implementation specific, but I never had this issue: `su && ls /data` via `adb shell` worked on my devices even with the ADB daemon running in "normal mode".